Allow WordPress Editor to access custom post type categories
I have a custom post type called "listings" and currently a user with an Editor role is able to access the post type but not the categories.
They are able to access, edit, add new, delete, etc anything on /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=listings but if they try to access the categories at /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=listings&page=listing_categories they are greeted with the following message: Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.
How can I allow users with an Editor role to access the categories page. As of now only admin user have access
I tried this to no avail...
function allow_user_edit_listings_post( $all_caps, $caps, $name, $user ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() && $name[0] == 'edit_post' ) {
        global $current_user;
        $post = get_post( $name[2] );
        if( in_array('author', $current_user->roles ) && ! is_wp_error($post) && $post->post_type == 'race' ) {
            $all_caps['edit_others_posts'] = true;
            $all_caps['edit_published_posts'] = true;
        }
    }
    return $all_caps;
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'allow_user_edit_listings_post', 10, 4 );

